# Как правильно xor'ить строки

Tags: c++

Требуется посимвольно выполнить операцию `xor` для двух строк одинаковой длины.
Когда пытаюсь сделать это так: `std::string A ^ std::string B` выводится ошибка:

> Ошибка: отсутствует оператор "^", соответствующий этим операндам. 
>   Типы операндов: `std::string ^ std::string`

Comment: Какого эффекта Вы хотите добиться от этого действия? Если `xor` для каждого символа, то это так и надо делать - посимвольно.

Comment: использовать operator[] ?

Comment: Зависит от задачи, которую Вы хотите решить. Вы так и не ответили для чего это понадобилось.

Comment: 2 строчки одинаковой длины посимвольно xor'ить

Comment: А чем вам не нравится цикл `for`? Проще не бывает.

Comment: @VladD мне кажется, просто было ожидание, что должно работать и для строковых операндов. А так, решение с циклом это, конечно, самое очевидное.

Answer (score 3):

Для посимвольной обработки строк можно использовать алгоритм `std::transform`. Так как в результате такой обработки могут получиться непечатные символы, на печать выводятся не сами символы, а их числовые коды:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s1("hello");
    std::string s2("world");
    std::string s3(5, ' ');

    std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s3.begin(), 
                   [](char c1, char c2){ return c1 ^ c2; });

    for(int i: s3) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы всегда можете сами сделать недостающий оператор:

```
std::string operator ^ (const std::string& s0, const std::string& s1)
{
    std::string result(s0.size(), '\0');
    std::transform(s0.begin(), s0.end(), s1.begin(), result.begin(), [](char c0, char c1) { return c0 ^ c1; });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Я думал что в C++ есть уже готовый метод, и не нужно городить костыли. Как же я был неправ

Comment: Т.к. размер результирующей строки известен до вызова `transform` лучше сразу зарезервировать достаточный размер вместо использования `push_back`. И передачу аргументов хорошо бы оформить в виде `const &`.